# jquery append multiple elements to a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to using jquery and I'm trying to append multiple elements to a div but I can't seem get the elements to append to the div how I want it to look.

[image: Here is a image of how I'm trying to get it to look]

```js
/** Dummy text start **/
var sender = "Sender Name";
var messageContent = "message content here";
var sent_at = "time here"
/** Dummy text end **/

var $chatlog = $('#chatlog');
var $div = $('<div />', { 'class': 'alert alert-secondary' });
var $sender = $('<strong />', { text: sender + ':' });
var $br = $('<br />')
var $message = $('<div />', { text: messageContent });
var $time = $('<small />', { class: 'pull-right', text: sent_at });
        
$chatlog.append($div.append($sender).append($br).append($message).append($time));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="chatlog"></div>
```

I can't work out how to do it or maybe there is a better way to do it that i don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css `bootstrap.min.css` (4.5.2) there isn't a class `pull-right` - there is a class `float-right` which is what you want.

In addition, you need to change the position of `$time` so that it appears at the top rather than after the message:

```js
/** Dummy text start **/
var sender = "Sender Name";
var messageContent = "message content here";
var sent_at = "time here"
/** Dummy text end **/

var $chatlog = $('#chatlog');
var $div = $('<div />', { 'class': 'alert alert-secondary' });
var $sender = $('<strong />', { text: sender + ':' });
var $br = $('<br />')
var $message = $('<div />', { text: messageContent });
var $time = $('<small />', { class: 'float-right', text: sent_at });
        
$chatlog.append($div.append($time).append($sender).append($br).append($message));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="chatlog"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this is how i was trying to get it to look! I thought there was a class pull-right but seems it was replaced with the float-left